# how to send erc20 token without using smart contract abi?

Tags: web3js, etherscan, ethereumjs-tx

How to transfer erc20 token without using contract or contract abi?

The below script i have used to create Signed Raw Transaction to send Ether(ETH).
 
**How can i create Signed Raw Transaction to send erc20 token with the same script by doing some modifications** 
what modifications are actually required i want to know and also i do not want to use smart contract abi.

```js
var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x1a',
  gasPrice: '0x4a817c800',
  gasLimit: '0xc350',
  to: '0x73F7Ced8cc9D27DC426210c32fc6d0a40f941eE1',
  value: '0x2386f26fc10000',
  data: '0x0',
  chainID: 4 
}      
var cTx = await new EthereumTx(rawTx, { 'chain': 'rinkeby' });
cTx.sign(privateKey);
var serializedTx = await cTx.serialize();
var cTxHash = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
```

Comment: You should encode the details (from , to, amount and function signature) and give it as data instead of '0x0' and 'to' is the address of the smart contract, 'value' should be 0. Anyway I'm sure someone asked about this before, if you didn't find an answer until tomorrow, I will weite a simple script for you

Comment: i didn't get answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode tha call to `transfer` into the data field.

- 4 bytes function signature of `transfer(address,uint256)`
- 32 bytes address parameter right aligned filled with zero bytes on the left
- 32 bytes amount paramter

For example if you want to transfer 0.2 DAI to `0xaaBBCcDDEeff00112233AaBbCcdDeEfF00112233`.

Your data field will be

- `a9059cbb` (function signature)
- `000000000000000000000000aabbccddeeff00112233aabbccddeeff00112233` (tokens recipient)
- `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb140000` (200000000000000000 because DAI uses 18 decimals)

So your raw transaction will be:

```
var rawTx = {
  nonce: '<whatever>',
  gasPrice: '<whatever>',
  gasLimit: '<whatever>',
  to: '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f', /// <---- DAI adress!!!!
  value: '0x0',
  data: '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000aabbccddeeff00112233aabbccddeeff0011223300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb140000',
  chainID: 4 
}
```

Comment: wow you just solved my all problems, i think i just need to write this concept in nodejs-> is there any script in nodejs so that i can do it very fast?

Comment: @IshwarChandra use this method to get the data
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall